# Conformal Field Theory and Langlands

Tags: ct.category-theory, rt.representation-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics

I'm a Mathematics masters student currently
studying some aspects of TQFT. I'm interested in Langlands, mainly
because it sounds oppressive! Is anyone familiar with any links between
CFT and Langlands, or more importantly any readable intros to these
sorts of areas.

How do Hecke Eigensheaves come into things? What does one need to know before hand. Are there any lists of requisite knowledge before tackling such concepts? Sometimes knowing where to start is a hard problem!

Comment: Did you mean to say "impressive" instead of "oppressive"?

Comment: Well, Scott, there are masochistic people who find oppressive things attractive :p

Comment: By the way, in number theory CFT = class field theory, which is the simplest (proved) instance of the Langlands program, so from that point of view asking about "links between CFT and Langlands" had me confused. I had to reread the question. 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a review article by Edward Frenkel which exactly fits your need: see ["Lectures on the Langlands Program and Conformal Field Theory"](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0512172). It's posted on hep-th, but as I (as a string theorist) had difficulties reading it, it should be written for mathematicians :)